# Delete all rows from Table not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Developing for Android using Xamarin
My problem is that when I issue "Delete from TAGS" in SQLITE the table still reports all the records exists.

```
So I am thinking there is some little detail that I am missing with how SQLite likes a table created or how to issue a delete command.

I have tried a couple of methods to this

1) db.delete("TAGS),null,null);
2) db.ExecSQL("Delete from TAGS");
3) sqlitecommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

I am NOT getting a locked table in DEBUG.
```

Comment: Please add more of your code, like how you handle the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you did not set the transaction successful. Try it like this:

```
 db.beginTransaction();
 db.delete("TAGS",null,null);
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Here is the function:public int deleteTAGS(Context context)
  {
   String DBName="IMDSARTS.db3";
   String Documents= System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

   var DB = Path.Combine (Documents, DBName);

   var SqlConnection =new SqliteConnection("Data Source="+DB);

   int rows = 0;
   SQLiteDatabase db = context.OpenOrCreateDatabase(DB,FileCreationMode.Private,null);
   db.BeginTransaction ();
   rows=db.Delete ("TAGS", null, null);
   db.SetTransactionSuccessful ();
   db.EndTransaction ();
   return rows;
  }

Comment: BTW the insert is being run on a worker thread. While the delete is run from the mainUIthread.

Comment: Oh, don't ever run database operations in the UI Thread, use an AsyncTask to do this. Also, try to use an SqliteOpenHelper to handle database opening, this is much easier and prevents errors. Please post this code to your Question, as it concerns everyone who might want to answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have the concept of an "auto commit". 
If you do not call "db.beginTransaction", then every insert/update/delete 
statement is wrapped in its own transaction. This behaves like "auto commit". 
If you do call "begin transaction", you start a transaction which you 
have to finish with "commit" or "rollback".

My guess is that you aren't getting the right database connection.

In your class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` you have two methods for getting a DB connection:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Make sure you are using the writable one for changing data.

Comment: It seems that no matter what approach I take the result is the same. This morning I created a very simple app that creates my tables adds 2 records and then when I push a button deletes the data. This works. But I am not seeing where I am doing anything special. However in the app I am working in the insert of the data is being done a thread that is listening for data from the Bluetooth device. Yesterday I even plugged in a delete command there so that as data was inserted it was deleted. The delete still does not take effect. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The answers give all work. The ultimate problem was that buffer I was using from the socket IO was not being cleared out after each insert. The delete did work, but the buffer used in the insert was running right after the delete function. Basically I was looking in the wrong place.